# How would I efficiently update potentially thousands of instances of a class at once?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I'm working on a plugin for a Minecraft server where you can connect redstone to the internet. The plugin works by using the lectern built into the game to be able to send/receive arbitrary redstone signals. It communicates with the internet using the MQTT protocol.

Currently, I have a lectern loader that is called `LecternHandlers` which loads a new instance of `LecternHandler` for each lectern that is created. All instances of `LecternHandler` are stored in an ArrayList formatted under the key/value of `<Location, LecternHandler>` with Location being the location of the lectern (this location stores both the world and coordinates and is a builtin feature of the Bukkit api).

As for data storage, I'm using MySQL to save the lecterns and the player settings in two different tables. The lectern table stores information such as the location of the lectern as well as its id. The player table stores information such as the MQTT broker to connect to, wether or not to use tls, authentication details, etc...

What I'd like to do is be able to update the player settings and the unload and reload the lecterns on the fly. Currently, I have to loop through each `LecternHandler` and check if it belongs to the player and then unload it and reload it. The `LecternHandler` will then retrieve the new settings from MySQL.

I believe this can cause performance issues if I am looping through thousands if not tens of thousands of lecterns at once, especially if the player themself has thousands of lecterns.

How can I solve the potential performance issue?

For those interested, [my project is on Github](https://github.com/alexis-evelyn/InternetRedstone/tree/current) under GPL-3 if you would like to see the code itself.

My goal is to make this plugin very efficient at handling a lot of lecterns so people won't have their server slow down due to a neat feature they would like to have.

Comment: Are you familiar with meta-programming? I'll rephrase that. You know rubber ducks? [Say hello to my lil' friend](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41IcbYtDf8L._AC_.jpg).

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with meta programming. While I know what rubber ducks are, but I'm not sure what they have to do with programming either, although it would probably make sense if I was familiar with meta programming.

Comment: Have you tried multithreading or do you want an optimization?

Comment: @user I currently use callbacks to pass functions to the HiveMQ library I use for MQTT. I don't have any asynchronous capable functions in my code other than the callbacks. As for updating the lectern from the callback, I have to use Bukkit's scheduler to put the code for updating the lectern on the main thread as manipulating the blocks in the world is not allowed due to how Minecraft currently handles block manipulation. I would say, I'm looking for a pointer on how to manipulate a subsection of a large amount of data efficiently.

Comment: When I said manipulating blocks isn't allowed, I meant it isn't allowed asynchronously. I will see about making the lectern handler loading and manipulation itself asynchronous as it doesn't touch the bukkit api except for the existing callbacks.

Comment: Deliver a message to one recipient. One recipient could be one recipient, or it could be an abstraction that is responsible for delivering to the next and ultimately all. Or you could take it literally.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I looked up rubber duck debugging and I find it quite interesting. I've used it so many times (but with explaining into a video instead of an inanimate object), to help me come up with solutions to problems I've had. That still doesn't help with this specific problem though, as I've already went and tried to brainstorm a solution (and even tried implementing extra data classes to use references and pointers only to realize I still don't efficiently reload the MQTT Client) before I asked for help on here.

Comment: It's difficult to offer helpful insights to such a vague question, especially given that I was little too old for Minecraft when it was first released. And I'm a lot too old now. I'm not sure why you must reload all of the lecturns. It would probably be best to do so lazily. Maybe mark the ones that depend on stale data as dirty and then use another process to reload dirty lecturns. I would not assume one approach will solve all the problems inherent in the design. But "reboot world" should probably be saved for emergencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent some time brainstorming on how to efficiently iterate and update potentially thousands of instances of a class.

First, I need to handle the classes asynchronously, so that when I perform heavy operations on large amounts of data, it won't lag the main thread. [Thanks to this comment by @user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350256/how-would-i-efficiently-update-potentially-thousands-of-instances-of-a-class-at#comment108532155_61350256) for reminding me that I can multithread code.

I then need to create another arraylist to handle referencing the lecterns owned by a specific player. The arraylist would look like `<UUID, LecternHandler[]>` to have an arraylist of instances of `LecternHandler` I can loop through. This will help me by only having me loop through a subsection of instances of `LecternHandler` instead of the full list. This is important as each LecternHandler has its own MQTT Client it handles (which runs asynchronously on its own right, but I need it to be better than that).

I can see about creating a player settings data class which is then referenced by each LecternHandler that belongs to that player. All instances of `LecternHandler` will hold a reference to the player settings which it would read from when it does get reloaded. I may hold off on this, as I am not sure how to make this thread safe if it's not already safe.

The `LecternHandler` itself should be fine being updated asynchronously as it doesn't rely on the Bukkit api except when receiving data from MQTT to update the current page the lectern is on (the current page changes the redstone output in a range of 1-15 and for those that don't know, redstone is Minecraft's version of electricity).

The only potential issue I see with this setup (which already exists in my current setup) is the potential ram usage due to loading thousands if not tens of thousands of instances of a class, however, that is out of the scope of this question.

This will allow the instances of `LecternHandler` to be able to be updated in batches or chunks which can be handled by the current jvm to prevent lag or freezing issues as it's not wasting the main thread's cpu cycle.

Comment: If anyone has any better solution to this, please post an answer, I'd love to learn how to better write my code in terms of performance and memory consumption. Thanks!